# Mixing with Maschine 2 software

Tags: recording, mixing

I have recorded a multi group sequence in Maschine 2.

In the mixing mode, if I am on a group that is a drum kit, I am able to adjust the volumes of each individual track without issue.

However, on the group that I recorded all the other sounds, whenever I try to adjust the volume of a specific track, all of the sliders move.

What I have noticed is that on the group for the drum kit, when i click on the sound heading, the whole area highlights, when I am on the group with my other recorded sounds, clicking on the sound heading does not highlight the whole area.

What am I missing here, how do I switch it so that I can adjust the individual track volumes from the mixer?

Below I have added a coupe of screen shots to show how on the drum kit group the whole track highlights, while on the other, it doesn't highlight.

Drum Kit Group:
[image]

Main Sounds Group:
[image]

Comment: You will probably get a better response if you post this in the NI forums, if you get an answer post it in here too.

Answer (score 2):

Hold [shift] and click any track.

The reason this is happening is because you have all of the tracks in the group highlighted/selected. Just hold [shift] + click any track in the mixer view -or- in the group view.